# How can I get all images from directory in Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURE and display in my custom gallery

Tags: android, android-image, android-gallery, android-cursor

I am making custom application galley for my application. Capture image from my custom camera and save image at xyz directory which is placed in  Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES. i want to access all those images and display in custom galley recyclerview. i try many ways but unable to get images. help me to fix this functionality thanks in advance.

```
   File fileX = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString(), "xyz");
        projection = new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", fileX),
                projection, null, null,null);

 //            private final String[] projection = new String[]{ MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,  MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME};

        if (cursor == null) {
            message = handler.obtainMessage();
            message.what = commonVariables.ERROR;
            message.sendToTarget();
            return;
        }

        ArrayList<Image> temp = new ArrayList<>(cursor.getCount());
        File file;
        folders = new ArrayList<>();

        if (cursor.moveToLast()) {
            do {
                if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                    return;
                }

                 long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(projection[0]));
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(projection[1]));
                String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(projection[2]));
                String bucket = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(projection[3]));
                DebugLog.e("MSG: PATH = > " + name );
//                    file = new File(path);
//                    DebugLog.e("MSG: Absolute PATH = > " + file.getAbsolutePath());
//                    if (file.exists()) {
//                        Image image = new Image(id, name, path, false);
//                        temp.add(image);
//
//                        if (folderMode) {
//                            Folder folder = getFolder(bucket);
//                            if (folder == null) {
//                                folder = new Folder(bucket);
//                                folders.add(folder);
//                            }
//
//                            folder.getImages().add(image);
//                        }
//                    }
```

It is giving me Argument Exception _ID not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
private void getImages() {
    String uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA;
    // if GetImageFromThisDirectory is the name of the directory from which image will be retrieved
    String condition = uri + " like '%/xyz/%'";
    String[] projection = {uri, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE};
    try {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection,
                condition, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            boolean isDataPresent = cursor.moveToFirst();
            if (isDataPresent) {
                do {
                    Log.e("ImagePath>>>", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(uri)));
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Don't forgot set permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Leave comment if any issue!

Comment: Cool answer but do you know how can we access those images or particular directory using cursor.

Comment: Awesome..... Thanxxx man... just tell me   " like '%/xyz/%'" what it means?

Comment: `" like '%/xyz/%'"` use for matching your particular directory